# Xcode crashes when creating outlet in OSX Yosemite

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, xcode

I am currently using Xcode 5 on my Macbook Pro which is running OSX Yosemite. I am trying to create an outlet from a UIWebview to a header file. When I let go of my mouse to create the connection, Xcode freezes and crashes. This is repeatedly happening no matter what I have done. I have tried restarting Xcode and my Macbook. Does anyone else have this problem or know how to fix it? Thanks!

Comment: Get Xcode 6? I don't know but Xcode 5 was definitely not created with Yosemite in mind.